# unable to interact with this dynamic drop down using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

[image: website screenshot]

hi team,

I am trying to access a dynamic drop down with div as tag but I an able find it but not interact with it
as it changes its style type as shown below.

```
<div style ="display :none;"></div>"
```

to

```
<div style ="display :block;"></div>"
```

I am unable to click on this, please have a look into the screenshot for detail.

Info you have to click on the element to access this dynamic dropdown,

Comment: it is much easier if you put URL as text in question (not in comment) and you add minimal working code - so we could copy it and test it .

Comment: `div` is not clickable object in HTML. If it has assigned some `JavaScript` code to display when you click it then you may need also `JavaScript` to click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution -> actually the element we are looking here is masked element which means actual Id of this element is diff so by chance I am able to find it( for this you have go through HTML code row by row and find it, quiet a static way to do but that's how I did it)  and place it in the code.

please do comment if you know more efficient way to work around masked elements.

Regards,
Anubhav

Answer (score 0):

`div` is not clickable object in `HTML`. If it has assigned some `JavaScript` code to display when you click it then you may need also `JavaScript` to click it

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", item)
```

and the same way you can change `style`

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", item)
```

---

In this minimal working example I remove all `img` on this page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
             
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931008/unable-to-interact-with-this-dynamic-drop-down-using-python-selenium'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img')
for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", item)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'none';", item)
```